# Selecting from query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying two write a query that Selects only the clientNo and how many house viewings they have had, but without and duplicate client numbers, does anyone know how I would do this?

so far all I've got is

```
SELECT clientNo FROM Viewing WHERE (viewDate LIKE
```

the desired output would be two columns one named clientNo and the numberOfViewings. clientNo containing the data stored in clientNo and numberOfViewing contining how many times a client has visited a house.

I have attached an image of the full table

[Table of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNB48.png)

Comment: SELECT distinct clientNo FROM Viewing WHERE (viewDate LIKE

Comment: Make it easy, and possible to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of wha tyou want.

Comment: i have now edited the question

Comment: Qustion has been answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `group by`?

```
SELECT clientNo, COUNT(*) as numberOfViewings
FROM Viewing 
GROUP BY clientNo;
```

Comment: One more question is there a way to change the column COUNT(*) to numberOfViewings>

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get it by using **group by**.
Try this one.

```
select clientNo,count(*) from viewing group by clientNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below select will work.

```
SELECT distinct clientNo, count(*) FROM Viewing group by clientNo
```